# How to get a Danish or German Dvorak layout in Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, dvorak

**Does an international Dvorak layout for Windows already exist?**

**Update:** I'm looking for a Dvorak layout that is **essentially the original US Dvorak layout but with international characters added** somewhere. I'm not interested in a fully localized layout based on the Dvorak principle.

I'm using Qwerty but I'd like to switch to Dvorak. Problem: I need to write international characters that are not available on Windows' built-in US Dvorak! I need to type Danish (æøå, ÆØÅ) and German (äöü ÄÖÜ) characters.

I once made a custom Dvorak layout from scratch using [MSKLC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx) but later could no longer install that tool to bugfix my layout. (I haven't tried installing it on my new Win7 installation yet.)

PS: As far as I can tell, not even Linux (Ubuntu) has a Danish or German Dvorak layout, only Norwegian which is close enough - but isn't Windows.

PPS: This is not a discussion about Dvorak vs. Qwerty. I appreciate the arguments for both sides, but this is simply a question about where to get the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is one already made with MSKLC.](http://www.dubaron.com/dvorak/dvorakdriver.html)

It's specifically made for the purpose you are looking for, adding additional international characters to the layout.

[Here are links to a repository of a few more.](http://keyboards.jargon-file.org/#USID)

Different source, same deal though.  It has KLC source files and image files of the layouts.

There are some 3rd party apps, but I don't really trust them.

Comment: Thanks, will look into that. Offtopic: I love your avatar! I have HAL on my iPhone lock screen :-)

Comment: @torbengb - glad you like it :)  HAL seems more and more appropriate as years go by.